# Blocking IE inline popup ads

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, hyperlink, internet-explorer-9

In IE (I'm testing on v.9), some text is automatically appended an anchor tag that contains advertising information.

In Firefox, this is not there. The site is pure html, but somehow IE is appending a link to it. It looks like this, a double-underlined link that is triggered on `hover`:

[image]

How can I get rid of this behavior, in either css or javascript? Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Jsfiddle or some code :P

Comment: If this is occurring just in IE then it's almost certainly caused by an IE add-on. It's not a programming issue: ask on [su]

Comment: I didn't add any add-ons this is a fresh IE install. I want to make sure that other IE users dont have to install an add-on to stop this behavior

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a programming question: EasyInline is a Yontoo adware that can be removed by uninstalling Yontoo Layers or removing the IE Add-On. Try superuser.com for more help.

Comment: This is a fresh IE install though. I didn't install any add-ons. How can I make sure this doesn't happen for other users without them having to install an add-on?

Comment: EasyInline is workstation-side adware. Period. You can't prevent it in code, because it's being appended to the payload delivered to the client by software local to their workstation. Again, www.superuser.com is where you want to be. Ask about dealing with easyinline.

Comment: It seems like there should be a way to watch for this using javascript though. Otherwise how does firefox automatically block this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Adware is one of the dangerous threat and it creates several trouble on your PC as well as on the web browser. It generate various online advertisements and pop-up ads to attract PC users and clicking any of the related ads redirect you to malicious websites. To remove the popup ads read the given below link as it also helped me to remove the annoying popup ads from my PC.

http://www.tabortvirusspyware.com/radera-trojanproxywin32bunitu-f-hur-tar-man-bort-trojanproxywin32bunitu-f